# Django with ./manager runserver works well, while Django + uwsgi return 404

Tags: python, django, static, nginx, uwsgi

This si my settings.py about `static` in `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/coat/www/site/app/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/",
# This is Django admin default static files
)
```

I user django server:

`./manager runserver`

Then I open the URL: `http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css`

It works very well.

But a open `http://localhost/static/admin/css/base.css`

It print '404'

[image]

I had restart Nginx and uwsgi for many times, but it dosen't works.

Comment: post nginx config for this site pls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first, this is *nonono*:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/coat/www/site/app/static/'
```

**Never** hardcode absolute paths, you're just making your settings file less portable and probably killing kittens. Adapt this to your needs:

```
import os.path
import posixpath

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

# fix STATICFILES_DIRS too
```

Now, to your question. django.contrib.staticfiles is fantastic but probably a little confusing at first.

1. You **must** understand the [collectstatic command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic):

   > Collects the static files into STATIC_ROOT. [...] Files are searched by using the enabled finders. The default is to look in all locations defined in STATICFILES_DIRS and in the 'static' directory of apps specified by the INSTALLED_APPS setting.
2. With runserver, staticfiles are served automatically, but in production mode (DEBUG=False, real HTTP server like Nginx), you should run collectstatic to (re)build STATIC_ROOT
3. STATIC_ROOT: is the root path where the HTTP server should serve static files **from**.
4. STATIC_URL: is the root URL where the HTTP server should serve static files **to**.
5. STATICFILES_DIRS: other static directories, in addition to each app's "static" subdirectory. Because django.contrib.admin is a normal app with a "static" folder, there is no need to specify it in the settings.

**Conclusion**: if STATIC_ROOT resolves to `/home/coat/www/site/app/static/`, and STATIC_URL is `/static/`, then you should:

1. Run collectstatic management command
2. Configure Nginx to serve `/home/coat/www/site/app/static/` on `/static/`, ie.:

   ```
   location ^~ /static/ {
       alias /home/coat/www/site/app/static/;
   }
   ```
3. Reload nginx

Answer (score 0):

In development the runserver command does some magic to serve your static files. In production you need to configure NGinx to do it. There are two chapters in the Django documentation I recommend you read:

1. [Serving static files in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production)
2. [Serving files (Deployment)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)

Especially the last link explains how you have to configure your NGinx to serve your static files.